# Why are Storyboards Disappearing in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have had an issue where my storyboards are disappearing from Main.storyboard on occasion. I was able to get one storyboard back by toggling size classes on and off. I have tried playing with the width and height values as well and nothing seems to be working.[image: First Missing Storyboard]

[image: Second missing Storyboard]

Any help getting this storyboards to show up again would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? I experienced a similar problem on a previous version but this is no longer the case. I am now using version Version 6.3.1 (6D1002)

Comment: I updated to 7 beta and it's gone